# python and list/dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm learning some list/dict comprehension and I'm stuck!!!

I really don't understand the following...

I have this program:

```
def histogram_for(word):
    adict = dict()
    for c in word:
        adict[c] = adict.get(c, 0) + 1
    print adict
    return adict

def histogram_dc(word):
    adict = dict()
    adict = {c: (adict.get(c, 0) + 1) for c in word}
    print adict
    return adict

def histogram_lc(word):
    adict = dict()
    adict = dict([(c, (adict.get(c, 0) + 1)) for c in word])
    print adict
    return adict


word = "Football"
histogram_for(word.lower())
histogram_dc(word.lower())
histogram_lc(word.lower())
```

And i get these results:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 2, 't': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 't': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'f': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 't': 1}
```

Why the only working one is the "for" method?

Comment: Consider using `collections.Counter` instead of writing your own histogram-generating functions.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply because while the processing is happening in `_dc` and `_lc` `adict` is empty, while in `_for` it's being updated on each turn of the `for` loop.  A comprehension can be de-sugared into a `for` loop of its own:

```
adict = dict()
adict = {c: (adict.get(c, 0) + 1) for c in word}
```

becomes:

```
adict = dict()
# Handwaving for what Python actually does
$newdict = {}
for c in word:
    $newdict[c] = adict.get(c, 0) + 1
adict = $newdict
```

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (or the for-loop version) if you need to keep track of a set of keys and counts of occurrences.

Comment: So i can't use comprehension for this purpose?

Comment: So my gut reaction when I saw `$newdict` was that you must've been coding in PHP or Perl all day and made an error when you posted here.  Then I realized that now all your variables use the `$`, so it must be on purpose.  But I haven't run across that notation before, and I can't find a reference to it.  What does it indicate?

Comment: @Doug - it's meant to indicate that the variable is a stand in for what the compiler actually does (e. g. "imagine that the compiler inserts another variable here")  I'll add a comment :-)

Comment: @SeanVieira - **whew!**  Thanks!  I thought there was a major gap in my Python.

Comment: @SeanVieira thanks for the latter answer but above you said "Quite simply because while the processing is happening in _dc and _lc adict is empty". It means that in the end list comprehension does not loop?

Comment: List comprehension loops, but it populates a different (anonymous) dictionary instance - and then *after that dictionary is populated* it assigns the final dictionary to `adict`.  So throughout the loop, `adict` is an empty dictionary and *after* the loop it now points at the anonymous dictionary that was populated (in a loop) by the comprehension.

Comment: @SeanVieira thank you very much! Sorry if I bother you, one last question. I'm a newbie ! Could you please explain better the doubt expressed by @Doug?

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Vieira said, the class [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its method `most_common` are the best solution to your need.

But, if you really want to keep list/dict comprehension, I suggest using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=count%20string#string.count) :

```
def histogram_dc(word):
  adict = dict()
  adict = {c: word.count(c) for c in set(word)}
  print adict
  return adict

def histogram_lc(word):
  adict = dict()
  adict = dict([(c, word.count(c)) for c in set(word)])
  print adict
  return adict
```